# peculiar teradata clause, Column_Name >= ''

Tags: teradata

I have a statament wrote for teradata by someone who don't work here anymore, so i can't ask him directly. 

In this statament, the last clause in the where is : `... and Column_Name >= ''` .I have no clue about what should that clause do. 

If it matter Column_name is a `[decimal](7,0) NULL`.

Can someone explain to me which case are accepted and which are refused by that clause ? 

to me it seams that should allow trough everything since everything is major or equal to `null`

Comment: When you compare a string to a numeric value the string is converted to a `FLOAT`, in your case the empty string `''` is treated as `0`, so this is just a stupid way to check for  `Column_Name >= 0` and filters negative values and `NULL`. You never know if this was actually the intention of the guy who wrote it :)

Comment: oh ok thanks, i supposed it may be something like that, but we are without any teradata server (it is a complicated situation) where to test how exactly was. if you want write it as an answer i'll be happy to accept it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare a string to a numeric value the string is converted to a `FLOAT`, in your case the empty string `''` is treated as `0`, so this is just a stupid way to check for `Column_Name >= 0` and filters negative values and `NULL`. You never know if this was actually the intention of the guy who wrote it :)

Answer (score 0):

When >='' clause is applied on a character column then it will restrict the null records.

If the table has 2 columns one Region_cd & rank_nr and the data in the table is as below:-

```
select * from databasename.tablename;

 *** Query completed. 5 rows found. Two column returned. 
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

Region    |      rank_nr
----------     -----------
emea      |          1
amr       |          2
apac      |          3
?         |          4
          |          5
```

? is represents NULL and space in region_cd column for rank=5 is not visible

If we query in this table with where clause as Region>='' then it will result below 4 rows:-

```
select * from databasename.tablename where Region_cd >='' ;
 *** Query completed. 4 rows found. 2 columns returned. 
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

col1      |    rank_nr
---------- -----------
emea      |          1
apac      |          3
amr       |          2
          |          5
```